# ruby idiom: predicates and the conditional operator

Tags: ruby, predicate, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I like judicious use of the ternary, conditional operator.  To my mind it's quite succinct.

However, in ruby, I find I'm often testing predicate methods, which already have their own question marks:

```
some_method( x.predicate? ? foo : bar )
```

I'm jarred by those two question marks so close to each other.  Is there an equivalently compact and readable alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest succinct expression you can get is

```
x.predicate? && foo || bar
```

which acts sort of a ternary operator, but more cryptic and ugly.

It's just a case of syntactic diabetes caused by the sugar on the `query?` methods. I guess we'll just have to learn to live with it.

Comment: +1 because this is more natural to Ruby. Thy ternary operator is an innovation so to speak and more cryptic as a result, whereas the use of  && and || against expressions is logical in that we know Ruby expression always return value and thus the code is what it means.

Answer (score 12):

The reason why the conditional operator is needed in C, is because the conditional statement is, well, a statement, i.e. it doesn't (and cannot) return a value. So, if you want to return a value from conditional code, you're out of luck. That's why the conditional operator had to be added: it is an expression, i.e. it returns a value.

In Ruby, however, the conditional operator is completely superfluous because there are no statements is Ruby anyway. *Everything* is an expression. Specifically, there is no `if` statement in Ruby, there is only an `if` expression.

And since `if` is an expression anyway, you can just use it instead of the cryptic conditional operator:

```
some_method( if x.predicate? then foo else bar end )
```

The only thing you have to remember is that the predicate needs to be terminated by either a newline, a semicolon or a `then`. So, the first three times you do this, you will turn

```
if cond
  foo
else
  bar
end
```

into

```
if cond foo else bar end
```

and wonder why it doesn't work. But after that, the `then` (or semicolon) will come naturally:

```
if cond; foo else bar end
if cond then foo else bar end
```

Comment: I upvoted, but really?  Cryptic?  I don't think any programmer would find the conditional operator cryptic, and personally I would rather see that than "if conditon foo else bar end" in a method call.

Comment: +1 because I think this is more readable than the "predicate? ?" implementation

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the space.

```
some_method( x.predicate?? foo : bar )
```

Is equally valid in Ruby. Try it!

Comment: +1 I don't like it — looks too much like a mistyped line — but it is a viable alternative.  (Interestingly, if you go through backflips to define a method 'predicate??' [sic] Ruby will still parse the above as calling 'predicate?'.)

Answer (score 1):

Can't say it's easier, but in many cases it might be useful just to wrap predicate itself into brackets, like this:

```
some_method((x.predicate?) ? foo : bar )
```

It helps, especially when your predicate is not as simple as `method?`